# Plots in lordif

Tags: r, plot

I'm using the package lordif and I was wondering why I can't get to all the maps
produced by the function [plot](http://127.0.0.1:17489/library/lordif/html/plot.lordif.html).

When I do the following

```
library(lordif)
data("Anxiety")
Age<-Anxiety$age
Resp<-Anxiety[paste("R",1:29,sep="")]
ageDIF<-lordif(Resp,Age,criterion="Chisqr",alpha=0.01,minCell=5)
plot(ageDIF,labels=c("Younger (<65)","Older (65+)"))
```

When I run the above I can see lots of maps as if I was flicking through a book but the only one that remains static is the very last one (showing difference between theta and theta-purified).

I've tried to use par(mfrow) but nothing changed. I've also tried to save the plot both manually and through R code but I still cannot access the whole set of plots.

1) How do I browse through the whole "plot book" and possibly save each image?

2) Is it possible to create two images one with plot 1-3 and another 4 to 7?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have been battling with this issue for a few days. I found that a solution that works for me (Windows 10, RStudio 4.2.1) is to add the `graphics.off()` parameter in the plot function. That is in your case:

```
plot(ageDIF, graphics.off(), labels=c("Younger (<65)","Older (65+)"))
```

That essentially stops the new device from opening in a new window and allows you to navigate through plots in the RStudio environment

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what environment you're running `R` from.  The documentation for `plot.lordif` is slim, but appears to suggest that the author intended for each graph to show up in a separate graphics window.  Can you generate multiple plots in your environment, e.g.,

```
% plot(x,y)
% dev.new() 
% plot(x,z)
```

If that works, then you probably should contact the `lordif` author directly to see what's up.

Answer (score -2):

Under Windows OS, the PageUp and PageDown keys can be used to navigate through the plots.